# Material UI slots

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to wrap my head up around the concept of `slots` in Material UI, but can't find a way to understand them, as I could not find any reference in the official documentation.

I see a lot of objects named`slots` in the Material UI core component library, can someone explain what are those and how are they used?

For instance in this function:

```
const useUtilityClasses = (ownerState) => {
  const { classes } = ownerState;

  const slots = {
    root: ['root'],
  };

  return composeClasses(slots, getCardUtilityClass, classes);
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Its using for Overriding nested component styles When you want to customize a specific part of a component. With API like this, you can create component for each of your slots, for example using styled components, with which you can theoretically opt-out of the styling mechanism that is used otherwise.
check this out for better understanding: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/21453

Comment: thanks! in the meantime I got more knowledge about slots, but your explanation sums it all super nice! thanks for the GitHub link also

Comment: additionally, linked issues of value include https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34333 and https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34334